# How to send selected cells from google sheets via appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

hello is any one familiar with app scripts?

I'm sending data from unity app to google sheets form then to template, send to a new spreadsheet be converted into pdf with needed data and then send as email,

I'm having trouble with the sheets, I have the where what I want to send should not go pass row 86.

In the email I get all rows of the new spreadsheet which is sending 7 pages, I only need one page to send for this or one range A1:AX86, I've been trying multiple solutions, anyone have a take on this

Thanks,

```
typefunction sendPdfEmailWithLatestData() {
  // Constants
  const SPREADSHEET_ID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const FORM_RESPONSE_SHEET_NAME = 'FormResponses';
  const PERIODONTAL_CHART_SHEET_NAME = 'Periodontal Chart';
  const EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Periodontal Chart';
  const EMAIL_BODY = 'Attached is the Periodontal Chart for your review.';




  // Get the active spreadsheet and the sheets by their name
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formResponseSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(FORM_RESPONSE_SHEET_NAME);
  const periodontalChartSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(PERIODONTAL_CHART_SHEET_NAME);

  // Get the range of all data in the FormResponses sheet, including the header row
  const formResponseDataRange = formResponseSheet.getDataRange();
  const numRows = formResponseDataRange.getNumRows();
  const numColumns = formResponseDataRange.getNumColumns();
  const values = formResponseDataRange.getValues();

  // Get the values from the latest row in the FormResponses sheet
  const headerRow = values[0]; // first row is the header row
  const latestRow = values[numRows - 1]; // last row is the latest row
  const patientLastName = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('Last Name')];
  const patientFirstName = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('First Name')];
  const patientDateOfBirth = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('Date of Birth')];
  const appointmentDate = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('Date')];
  const appointmentTime = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('Time')];
  const appointmentVisit = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('Visit')];
  const patientEmail = latestRow[headerRow.indexOf('Email')];

  // Update the values in the Periodontal Chart sheet
  const columnNames = ['E7:L7', 'Q7:X7', 'AC7:AJ7', 'AM7:AO7', 'AR7:AT7', 'AW7:AX7'];
  columnNames.forEach(function(columnName) {
  // Clear the contents of the cells in the specified column
  periodontalChartSheet.getRange(columnName).clearContent();
});
  const valuesToSet = [patientLastName, patientFirstName, patientDateOfBirth, appointmentDate, appointmentTime, appointmentVisit];
  columnNames.forEach((columnName, index) => {
    periodontalChartSheet.getRange(columnName).setValue(valuesToSet[index]);
  });

 

  // Convert the active spreadsheet to a PDF file and save it to Google Drive
  const pdf = DriveApp.createFile(activeSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf'));

  pdf.setName('Periodontal Chart.pdf');

  // Send the email with the PDF file attached
  //GmailApp.sendEmail(patientEmail, EMAIL_SUBJECT, EMAIL_BODY, {attachments: [pdf]});

  // Delete the PDF file from Google Drive
  pdf.setTrashed(true);

 
  console.log(`Latest row: ${latestRow}`);
copySheetAndSendEmail(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), patientEmail, "Periodontal Chart", "Attached is the Periodontal Chart for your review.",PERIODONTAL_CHART_SHEET_NAME);

}

function copySheetAndSendEmail(sourceSpreadsheet, emailAddress, emailSubject, emailBody, PERIODONTAL_CHART_SHEET_NAME) {


  // Get the source sheet
  const periodontalChartSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(PERIODONTAL_CHART_SHEET_NAME);
  // Create a new spreadsheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Periodontal Chart");

  // Copy the sheet to the new spreadsheet, including data and formatting
  periodontalChartSheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Periodontal Chart.pdf");

  // Get all sheets in the newSpreadsheet
  var sheets = newSpreadsheet.getSheets();

  // Loop through all sheets
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];

    // If the sheet is not the Periodontal Chart sheet, delete it
    if (sheet.getName() != "Periodontal Chart.pdf") {
      newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
  }

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
for(var i=87;i<=sheet.getLastRow();i++){
  sheet.hideRow(i);
}

  // Convert the specified range of cells to a PDF file and save it to Google Drive
  const pdf2 = DriveApp.createFile(newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf'));


  // Send the email with the PDF file attached
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailBody, {attachments: [pdf2]});
 
 
  // Delete the new spreadsheet
  pdf2.setTrashed(true);
} here
```

If I manually goto file download in sheets I will get the export options for the pdf, though I'm not sure how to fully implement via app scripts

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! You might want to add the ```google-apps-script``` tag to find answers related to your code

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889478/getsheetbyname-function-not-working-when-creating-pdf/74890712#74890712